# Extracting substring in python string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a pandas column like this:

```
LOD-NY-EP-ADM
LOD-NY-EC-RUL
LOD-NY-EC-WFL
LOD-NY-LSM-SER
LOD-NY-PM-MOB
LOD-NY-PM-MOB
LOD-NY-RMK
LOD-NY-EC-TIM
```

I want the output in new column as

```
EP
EC
EC
LSM
PM
PM
RMK
EC
```

I tried this:

```
pattern=df.column[0:10].str.extract(r"\w*-NY-(.*?)-\w*",expand=False)
```

While it works for everything but it fails to get RMK out and gives NaN since there is nothing after that and it looks for -\w zero or more times. But then that should work if there is nothing after RMK.

Any idea whats going wrong?

We can just use a array of these and use regular expression if pandas syntax is not familiar.

Comment: Try [`^\w+-NY-(.*?)(?:-\w+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/7Yq4ph/1)

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use regular python?
Let df be your dataframe, and row be the name of your row.

```
series = df.row
new_list =  [i.split('-')[2] for i in series]
new_series = pd.Series(new_list)
```

Comment: can we try with regular expression? I can also use slice method and count the index there. But wanted to check if regular expression makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern=df.column[0:10].str.extract(r"\w*-NY-(\w+)",expand=False)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/3uDpam/3

Your regex meant matching strings must have 3 `-` characters.  I changed it so last `-XX` could occur 0 or 1 times.

UPDATE: Changed so 2nd group is non-capturing (added `?:`)

UPDATE: Thanks to Casimir, removed useless group at end of pattern

Comment: something is weird. It works if i just try this regex on a string. But when I am trying on pandas column as above, it is giving even the  hyphen along with the extracted string. And still fails for RMK. But that RMK thing works fine if I just use it on a string

Comment: Maybe Pandas is using the last matching group.  Try this `\w*-NY-(\w+)(?:-\w+)?`  (so the 2nd group is non-capturing)

Comment: Ok i got the issue. It is also adding a column for third group (extracting the last letters also). I dont want that. I only want the first group to be extracted. How do we do group(0) in pandas extract?

Comment: is there any info on this like how do u know by adding ?: makes it work?

Comment: Since it is optional, writing `(?:-\w+)?` at the end of a pattern is useless. (writing something optional at the end of a pattern is always useless, except if you have to capture something inside this optional part).

Comment: D-oh, Casimir is right.  Use this `\w*-NY-(\w+)` as the complete regex.